# Adding a linear-gradient to a border via :root var in CSS?

Tags: css

How can I add a linear-gradient to a root var in my CSS?

```
 :root {
--primary: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(24,238,255,1) 0%, rgba(48,223,255,1) 100%);
```

}

```
 border: solid 1px var(--primary);
```

I'm trying to do something like this, but it isn't working.

Comment: why would you need my html when I'm creating a custom root variable. If I put green, it will show, but for linear gradients you need a background, so that's why I'm trying to see how that's possible with a root var

Answer (score 0):

Your gradient values seem to the same color so there is no effect when i tested.

I have added secondary and primary random color to linear gradient for you you can change them as you want.

To apply css via `:root` to the `border` you need to use `border-image:` css property and `border-image-slice` for the border

I have added `border 4px solid` for *testing purposes* and some padding as well.

To read more about using `linear gradients` on `border-image` and [border-image-slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-image-slice) here is the official [MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-image)

Run snippet below to see it working.

```css
:root {
  --primary: 78, 137, 176, 1;
  --secondary: 115, 192, 85, 1;
}

p {
  border: 4px solid;
  border-image: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(var(--secondary)) 0%, rgba(var(--primary)) 100%);
  border-image-slice: 1;
  padding: 4px;
}
```

```html
<p>We can take advantage of being able to apply CSS to the and keep our markup clean!</p>
```